# How to use PJSIP library in Xcode - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip

I installed the PJSIP library in Xcode by CocoaPods in order to integrate video entryphone calls into my app.

After that, how do I use this PJSIP library into Xcode?

Comment: Little googling and I have found https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Answer (score 0):

You should start by studying the source code of an iOS app sample using this library.

For example: https://github.com/DXI-Ltd/PjSIP

You should also study the library license terms as the library is GPL. If you want to distribute your app, you have to arrange alternative licensing with PJSip owners.

Comment: Thank you so much I will download that project. Is Installing the library with CocoaPods enough in order to make it works? Or need some more procedure?